# Return intersection points and objects intersecting

Tags: c++, cgal

I am a beginner in CGAL and I have a question about the intersections of segments (maybe arcs too).

Given that I have two lists of segments, where each list represents a shape, if I put these two forms to intersect, is there any way to get the points of intersection and yours segments?

Here is a example: http://imagizer.imageshack.us/v2/800x600q90/13/ydtj.png
I want the dark green/blue segments and the intersection point in light green/blue. The image shows the two intersections, but for my purpose it was enough only the first intersection.

I thought to iterate through the lists, but I think this may be a naive approach. There is a more accurate and fast way to do this?

Comment: http://doc.cgal.org/latest/Sweep_line_2/index.html

Comment: Interesting to imagine that a curve can represent a line segment. But I want the two segments (curves) intersecting, and not the disjoint sub-curves.

In this picture I have the result of compute_subcurve http://imagizer.imageshack.us/v2/800x600q90/163/6nxn.png
And I want the complete curves AB, CD or EF, GH. 

How can I solve this? Arrangements?

And thanks for the help.

Comment: I did some research and made an example using arrangements.
http://pastebin.com/SmueNLQe
http://pastebin.com/Dx7K7ps5
http://pastebin.com/zU6fG0AV

And here is the graphical representation http://imagizer.imageshack.us/v2/800x600q90/843/fkj5.png

I saw in the CGAL documentation merge_edge can use to join two edges. And I realized that if I use the points of intersection and iterate between neighboring edges, you can create edges. But what if a segment of an arrangement intersect more than one time in a different arrangement of the segments? how can I join all these sub-curves?

Comment: Just to make sure I understand. The vertices you get easily using the 2D arrangement package, right? The *segments* you refer to are those that contain the intersection points?

Comment: Yes, I can easily get the point of the arrangement. And I want the original segment that contains (not the interior-disjoint segments) the point of intersection.

Answer (score 1):

Somehow get the original primitive. I just used an Arrangement_with_history_2.
Can also be used an Arr_curve_data_traits_2 to store the original curve, but it is not as simple as using a history.

In the end, I discovered how to get the original segments, but my problem is still far from being solved.

Thanks for the help.